# preventing parleyjs multiple steps to continue if a condition is not met

Tags: javascript

I'm using parsleyjs to validate a form and I'm using the "multiple steps" script found at: http://parsleyjs.org/doc/examples/multisteps.html.

All works great on its own, but I have a set of fields (datetimepicker) that I reset if the end date is less then the start date.

What it does it is simply shows an alert and clears the field when the user clicks "Next".

I thought that with clearing the fields, since they are required the form would not proceed, but it continues to the next page. If I go back and then next again, then it prevents as expected. It's as if the click beats the textbox clearing.

Here is my example in step 2 if you add a start date less then the end date

https://www.blinn.edu/expansion/facilities-listing/form-2-a.HTML

and the code:

```js
 // raul - 3-8-2019 - created a javascript to compare dates and pass them to the HTML file. this method had to be done this way becasue the Velocity file was converting the > sign into HTML entities
 
 //var startDate = "03/13/2019 9:39 AM"; //$(".datetimepicker1 input").val();
 var startDate = $(".datetimepicker1 input").val();

    var start_date = new Date(startDate);

 //var endDate = "03/13/2019 9:40 AM"; //$(".datetimepicker2 input").val();
 var endDate = $(".datetimepicker2 input").val();
  
 var end_date = new Date(endDate);
 
 //sample1 Fri Mar 08 2019 09:48:16 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)
 //sample2 Wed Mar 13 2019 09:40:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)
 
 
   return compDate();
   
   
       function compDate() { 

            if (end_date >= start_date) {
               
              //$('.form-control, .submit').attr('disabled', 'disabled'); //Disable   
               //alert(end_date + " is greater than " + start_date);
                    
             }
             else if (end_date < start_date){
              
              //$('.form-control, .submit').removeAttr('disabled'); //enable
                    alert(end_date + " is less than " + start_date);
                    $(".datetimepicker1 input").val(""); // reset the datetimepicker
                    $(".datetimepicker2 input").val(""); // reset the datetimepicker 
                    e.preventDefault();
                    return false;
                    
             }
             
             else {
                 
                    $('.form-control, .submit').removeAttr('disabled'); //enable
                    //alert("no condition met");
             }
         
    }
// raul - 3-8-2019 - created a javascript to compare dates and pass them to the HTML file. this method had to be done this way becasue the Velocity file was converting the > sign into HTML entities
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

I had to put all of that code in a function before the "multiple step" script and then call it before the previous/next script took place. Not the best solution, but it works for now. Still hope to find a more elegant soulution

```js
$('.form-navigation .previous').click(function() {
/////////////added function here to call it before the "previous" occurred
    navigateTo(curIndex() - 1);
  });


  $('.form-navigation .next').click(function() {
/////////////added function here to call it before the "next" occurred

    $('.demo-form').parsley().whenValidate({
      group: 'block-' + curIndex()
    }).done(function() {
      navigateTo(curIndex() + 1);
    });
  });
```